# Consider the numbers of length 8 over 10 ten digits, (0 - 9) how many numbers contain at least two 2's?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Numbers may begin with 0, so 00000000 is valid.

How many of these numbers contain at least two 2's?

What is the probability of a number containing at least two 2's?

I got as far as deducting the permutations that definitely don't meet the criteria. Which I think would be $9^{8}+9^{7}\cdot10$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  How many contain $0$ twos?  How many contain exactly $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10^{8}$ numbers possible.

To count the numbers with at least $2$ $2$'s, we will count the number with less than $2$ and subtract from $10^{8}$ (this method is called complementary counting). There are $9^{8}$ numbers that do not contain a $2$, and $8\cdot 9^{7}$ numbers containing exactly $1$ $2$. (Note that we must pick which digit will be a $2$, and then the rest of the digits must not be $2$'s.) Thus, there are $\boxed{10^{8}-9^{8}-8\cdot 9^{7}}$ numbers containing at least $2$ $2$'s.

To get the probability, we must divide by the total number, for an answer of $\boxed{\frac{10^{8} - 9^{8}-8\cdot 9^{7}}{10^{8}}.}$

Comment: Why $9^{7}\cdot8$ wouldn't you have 10 options for the column that could potentially have a 2 making it $9^{7}\cdot10$?

Comment: $8\cdot 9^{7}$ comes from (first) choosing which of the $8$ digits will be a $2$ (second) choosing which numbers the $7$ remaining digits will be